# EmberFire and nested arrays

Tags: ember.js, firebase

I'm attempting my first ember-based project, as well as integrating emberfire into it to get Firebase capabilities. I'm building a tree menu builder, for another project.

The json for the firebase database is as follows:

```
    {
  "default" : {
    "_type" : "arrayObject",
    "name" : "unnamed",
    "_name" : "default",
    "menus" : {
      "Top" : {
        "menu" : {
          "2" : {
            "text" : "0-2",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 0,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : 0,
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : 0
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : 208,
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : 208
            },
            "row" : 2,
            "id" : 2
          },
          "5" : {
            "text" : "0-5",
            "actions" : [ {
              "action" : 3
            } ],
            "column" : 0,
            "color" : {
              "b" : 0,
              "g" : 0,
              "a" : 255,
              "r" : 0
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : 208,
              "g" : 208,
              "a" : 255,
              "r" : 208
            },
            "row" : 5,
            "id" : 5
          },
          "12" : {
            "text" : "1-3",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 1,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "row" : 3,
            "id" : 12
          },
          "15" : {
            "text" : "1-6",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 1,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "row" : 6,
            "id" : 15
          },
          "8" : {
            "text" : "0-8",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 0,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "row" : 8,
            "id" : 8
          },
          "_type" : "objectArray",
          "7" : {
            "text" : "0-7",
            "actions" : [ {
              "action" : 3
            } ],
            "column" : 0,
            "color" : {
              "b" : 0,
              "g" : 0,
              "a" : 255,
              "r" : 0
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "visible",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : 208,
              "g" : 208,
              "a" : 255,
              "r" : 208
            },
            "row" : 7,
            "id" : 7
          },
          "17" : {
            "text" : "1-8",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 1,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "row" : 8,
            "id" : 17
          },
          "1" : {
            "text" : "0-1",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 0,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : 0,
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : 0
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : 208,
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : 208
            },
            "row" : 1,
            "id" : 1
          },
          "4" : {
            "text" : "0-4",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3
              }
            },
            "column" : 0,
            "color" : {
              "b" : 0,
              "g" : 0,
              "a" : 255,
              "r" : 0
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : 208,
              "g" : 208,
              "a" : 255,
              "r" : 208
            },
            "row" : 4,
            "id" : 4
          },
          "11" : {
            "text" : "1-2",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 1,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "row" : 2,
            "id" : 11
          },
          "14" : {
            "text" : "1-5",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 1,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "row" : 5,
            "id" : 14
          },
          "6" : {
            "text" : "0-6",
            "actions" : [ {
              "action" : 3
            } ],
            "column" : 0,
            "color" : {
              "b" : 0,
              "g" : 0,
              "a" : 255,
              "r" : 0
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "visible",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : 208,
              "g" : 208,
              "a" : 255,
              "r" : 208
            },
            "row" : 6,
            "id" : 6
          },
          "0" : {
            "text" : "0-0",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 0,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : 0
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : 208
            },
            "row" : 0,
            "id" : "0"
          },
          "9" : {
            "text" : "1-0",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 1,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "row" : 0,
            "id" : 9
          },
          "16" : {
            "text" : "1-7",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 1,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "row" : 7,
            "id" : 16
          },
          "3" : {
            "text" : "0-3",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 0,
            "color" : {
              "b" : 0,
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : 0,
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : 0
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : 208,
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : 208,
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : 208
            },
            "row" : 3,
            "id" : 3
          },
          "10" : {
            "text" : "1-1",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 1,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "row" : 1,
            "id" : 10
          },
          "13" : {
            "text" : "1-4",
            "actions" : {
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "0" : {
                "action" : 3,
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "column" : 1,
            "color" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "_type" : "object",
            "visibility" : "hidden",
            "page" : 0,
            "bgColor" : {
              "b" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "_type" : "objectArray",
              "g" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "a" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              },
              "r" : {
                "_type" : "object"
              }
            },
            "row" : 4,
            "id" : 13
          }
        },
        "_type" : "object"
      },
      "_type" : "objectArray"
    },
    "id" : "default"
  },
  "_type" : "objectArray",
  "app2" : {
    "_type" : "arrayObject",
    "name" : "app2",
    "_name" : "app2",
    "menus" : {
      "Top" : [ {
        "text" : "0-0"
      } ],
      "_type" : "objectArray"
    }
  }
}
```

Anyhow, I've succeeded using a fork of emberFire that provides an emberFire object out of my initial array.(https://github.com/ember-meteor/emberFire/blob/refactor/emberfire-latest.js)

That works.

I have an embedded array that I turn into another emberFire ObjectArray, and

my code:https://github.com/jondthompson/menutest.

I used a similar behavior to the original ObjectArray creation to create a second one for the 'ssMenus'  array nested within the 'ssApp', but it appears to not be populating with the proper data from Firebase, nor is the router even firing with an empty array.

The proper behavior would be when you click on an 'app', the name of the app appears at the bottom (works!), with the names of the menus appearing next to it (doesn't).

Anyhow, Help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

- I was writing the child firebase reference manually. I figured out how to do it via the original firebase object.
- I wasn't encapsulating the child reference in a firebase object, but rather I was trying to inject it somewhere it didn't belong.
- I was trying to create a second route, when I didn't need it.

I may have missed something else too. I consider myself a beginner programmer, so this is stretching my abilities.

My original AppController..

```
App.SsAppController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ["selected_ssApp", 'ssMenus'],

  selected: function(){
    return this.get('controllers.selected_ssApp.model') === this.get('model');
  }.property('controllers.selected_ssApp.model', 'model'),

  actions: {
    select: function(){
      var model = this.get('model');
      var menuList = this.get('controllers.ssMenus')
      Ember.debug("MenuList: "+ menuList);
      this.set('controllers.selected_ssApp.model', model);
      menuList.set('ref', new Firebase("https://menutest.firebaseio.com/jt-test/"+model.content._name+"/menus"));

    }
  }
});
```

My new and improved (read: working) MenuController..

```
App.SsAppController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ["selected_ssApp", 'ssMenus'],
    menus: function(){
        var model = this.get('model'),
        ref = model.get('ref');

        return EmberFire.ObjectArray.create({ ref: ref.child('menus')});
    },
  selected: function(){
    return this.get('controllers.selected_ssApp.model') === this.get('model');
  }.property('controllers.selected_ssApp.model', 'model'),
  actions: {
    select: function(){
      var model = this.get('model'),
      menusObj = model.get('menus');
      this.set('controllers.selected_ssApp.model', model);

        this.set('controllers.ssMenus.content', this.menus());
    }
  }
});
```